# Depictions of Lord Krishna or Rama in old age

Tags: krishna, rama, art

I am looking for authentic art of Krishna or Rama in which they are depicted in old age. (Not old as in ancient art, old as in body-form.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141757/discussion-on-question-by-blue-ego-is-there-any-old-aged-art-or-sculpture-of-lor).

Comment: You  might want to understand how Sri Krishna's life ended first...

Answer (score 1):

**Lord Rama and Lord Lakshmana with Vanar Sena with rare beared look.:**

[image]

**Lord Krishna with moustache.:**[image]

**Lord Vishnu with Moustache.:**[image]

**As for Old, I can only give you the picture of Lord Parshurama.:**[image]

**[Another One](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHkWPX2dsbg1AYEQCT3PfNCOKEbYxmHUPqAB--q9Kz7DgGQCdr).**

**[Lord Rama with moustache](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Lord_Rama_with_arrows.jpg/696px-Lord_Rama_with_arrows.jpg).**

I hope this clarifies your queries. Prd..

Comment: Not bad, could you please tell who made the first painting/drawing, and its source. And the second and third photos seem to be photos of some temple sculptures, could you tell the names of those temples. I am just curious, I didn't want to bother you. If it is bother, please don't mind this message.

Comment: Its ok, n not bothering. The 1st pic is from Balasaheb Pant Picture Ramayana, Lord Krishna one is from Partha Sarathi (Arjuna's Charioter) temple, Lord Vishnu's one m not sure but i think its from south, can't confirm it cz i saw similar scriptures of Lord Shiva also in South with similar type of sculpture making style. I think i saw another such sculpture of Lord Vishnu with moustache in fb or somewhere but can't remember the exact post. Not bad right cz its not a mandatory rule for deities to remain clean shaved. Anyways, i thos helps you. Chalo cya tc.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively old Arun Govil as Shri Ramchandra

[image: Relatively old Arun govil as Sri Ram]

Sita Devi Bhumi Pravesh by Raja Ravi Varma

[image: Sita Bhumi Pravesh by Raja Ravi Varma]

In these photos Sri Ram looks older than usual still not old enough.

Comment: The former one isn't painting or sculpture but a photo of an actor in costume. In the latter one, Rāma surely looks a bit middle-aged but not even a bit old , as you already pointed out. Please share who drew the painting. The style looks similar to that of Raja Ravi Varma, but I am not sure if it is his work or not .

Comment: Dude. .. .. the picture of Arun Govind Sir...

Comment: I didn’t recognize Arun G ! I think he was good in the role of Ram  Lots of sincerity. I liked the guy playing Lakshman too. I liked the scene where Lakshman gets all mad suspecting Bharat when Bharat comes to visit them in the forest. But then he realizes Bharat didn’t do anything. Good stuffs 